# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi ip-config-unavailable

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, realtek

I have the realtek pci rtl8732be wireless card. I am able to connect to ethernet and open wireless connections. When I tried to connect to my university wifi(WPA2 PEAP) it tries to connect and then times out. I started facing this problem after I reinstalled ubuntu. According the log, the reason seems to be "ip-config-unavailable." Can anyone provide me assistance with this problem.

[network manager log](https://gist.github.com/rishikeshdevsot/1dfcb136122a7f391658a50696780fd6)

Comment: You're timing out waiting for a DHCP response.

Comment: I have made it run for more than 2mins and its still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed now. I had to disable secure boot on the BIOS.